# Attaching a location value to a list when printed

Tags: python, python-3.x

So i have a adventure game and i created a list of locations

```
rooms = [ "You are in the garden. Darkness everywhere.",
          "You are in the bathroom. You sound some noise.",
          "You are in the hall. You almost fall. Stairs east",
          "You are in the kitchen. You can hear voices.",
          "You are in the upstairs hallway. It's quiet. Stairs North.",
          "You are in your room. You're safe." ]
```

For each line if it executes i want it to print lets say

```
Location 0
You are in the garden. Darkness everywhere.
```

I am confused on how to go about it. I know how to just make it say something like

```
Location 0 You are in the garden. Darkness everywhere.
```

but that is not required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each line in the format you want: `Location 0 You are in the garden. Darkness everywhere.`, the number is the index of the string within the `room` list.

Doing a loop such as this:

```
for i in range(len(rooms)):
    print('Location %d %s' % (i, rooms[i]))
```

Will give you the desired output for all of the strings in the list.

In that code segment, `%d` represent a formatted number variable, in this case being the number of the location, and `%s` representing the string to be printed, being the string within that location of the list.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `enumerate` function.

```
for i,description in enumerate(rooms):
    print(i, description)
```

Comment: This answer is the better one. In @m_callens's answer the length of the rooms is calculated, whereas this one returns a generator which only evaluates the rooms object's final index conditionally.